# What natural occurences can be blamed on Witches but also explained with medieval science

Tags: medieval, outdated-science

I want to write a Story about a medieval village
This Village is plagued by a lot of misfortunes and as people are they blame it on witches but i am having a hard Time finding good occurences.
The Thing is:
They need to be explainable by a medieval science guy
and the explanations does not have to be correct but belivable by "sience" and some wishfull thinking that magic does not exist.

Comment: This is quite vague. It could be droughts, floods, wildfires, etc. What makes one answer better than another?

Comment: Lightning was considered as a sign of the wrath of gods in certain cultures and basically monsters in others. Basically any event you can't quite explain at your current period and level of understanding of the world can be attributed to magic, and by proxy to witches, including technology too advanced for them to understand. It might be better if you elaborate the things a best answer should have to be considered as such so your question doesn't get closed as opinion based. Welcome to WBSE. Make sure to make our [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) on how the site works.

Comment: Proving a negative is notoriously difficult.  If my crops failed because it did not rain how can one prove the witch did not prevent rain?  If my livestock got sick, the fact that other people had sick livestock does not prove the witch was not behind all of it.  The fact that she cannot do magic on demand is no proof either; I can bake bread, but not at the snap of a fingers - it takes ingredients and setting up.  For your story you can have an educated skeptic like Maimonides.  But even today, it is just about impossible to get believers to stop believing.

Comment: Hello @Jadewolf, thanks for asking your first question. Unfortunately, there's not enough information here to effectively answer the question, so I'm going to VTC:NDC. This isn't a punishment, it (when combined withe the other 4 votes) is a pause. I'll be happy to retract when you [edit] your Q and add the clarifications. The medieval era was from the 5th to the 15th century A.D. That's an ***enormous*** period of scientific change. Also, there's a huge difference between London, Bucharest, and Cairo. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ...So we need to know the exact reference date that reflects the tech level of your story and a specific city that reasonably reflects the culture of your people. Next, to turn this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609), we need to understand the scope of the effect you're looking for. You can't have everything, that's fishing for ideas and off-topic. Are we looking for personal-effects, city-wide effects, or regional effects? ...

Comment: ... Finally, Stack Exchange's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer, and the question is expected to be objective. To avoid your question being opinion-based (which it is), you need to provide either the limitations and restrictions of the rules of your world (what limits the witches? They're not gods...), and/or (preferably and) you need to explain the criteria of a best answer. How will you judge? Please keep in mind SE is not a discussion forum and if you just want us to brainstorm then you've asked an off-topic question. [Edit] your Q and I'll retract my vote. Thanks!

Comment: Approximately what year does this story occur? The scientific method was "discovered" around the 1600's.

Comment: One thing to remember is that the church tried multiple times to blame witches for things. And only on the third time did it work. The first two times the people laughed at the church.

Comment: Actually, @NomadMaker, the general population was much more eager to blame people as witches than the Church.  The Church would explicitly declare that some things they were claiming were impossible, and the people would still go and kill others as witches.

Comment: @Mary, please read history. The church was the one who riled up the people against witches. It took three tries, many years apart, until on the third try it worked. I'm sure that there were always a few who had the "witch fever", but the church was the one who pushed it. Also, there were strong economic incentives to convict witches. It was a time of hypocrisy all around.

Comment: @NomadMaker please read history.  Your claim is obviously false not only because it does not match the history of Europe, but because witch hunts occur throughout the world.

Answer (score 2):

Just about anything could be blamed on witches, including a stillborn calf, a bad year for crops, an accidental fire, or a plague. During the witch hunts, Witches were blamed for just about anything that went wrong. Most of these things are just bad things that happen sometimes, but people really like having someone to blame for their misfortune. and the trouble with this is that even if you can find a definite cause, the folks might still blame the witch.

Say a cow knocks a lantern over and burns down half of Chicago (which actually happened once, by the way.) The people might blame a witch for the fire. If someone discovers what really happened, the people might still blame the witch for jinxing the lantern to fall over.

In most cases, though, there won't be a clear, underlying cause; the event will have been caused by multiple things far outside of anyone's control. A bad harvest might be caused by a drought, which might have been caused by unusually weak winds that year. The townsfolk likely won't be super happy with that answer; they want a specific person to blame.

Comment: This is besides the point but I thought that story about the Chicago fires was a myth

Comment: It seems the cow story may not have been true, but it's not entirely off the table. https://www.thoughtco.com/mrs-olearys-cow-great-chicago-fire-1774059

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off concentrating -- as those who opposed witch-hunting often did -- on the difficulties of proving that a person is a witch responsible for a given harm.

For instance, take a storm that ruined crops or sank a ship.  We would be hard put nowadays to **prove** that a storm was not caused by witchcraft.  But rigorous judges would demand answers to question such as these:

- How do you know that storm was not a natural occurrence?
- If you have evidence that it was not natural, how do you know it was caused by witchcraft rather than divine intervention, or a devil's work?
- If you have evidence that it was witchcraft, do you have evidence that this person was the witch responsible?

Those who claimed that a witch could not do things would do so on theological grounds, not scientific.  For instance, the Church taught that it was impossible for a witch to affect the weather.